# Trouble graphing two columns on one graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I just started learning R.  I melted my dataframe and used ggplot to get this graph.  There's supposed to be two lines on the same graph, but the lines connecting seem random.

Correct points plotted, but wrong lines.

[image]

```
# Melted my data to create new dataframe
AvgSleep2_DF <- melt(AvgSleep_DF ,  id.vars = 'SleepDay_Date', 
variable.name = 'series')

# Plotting
ggplot(AvgSleep2_DF, aes(SleepDay_Date, value, colour = series)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = series)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = series))
```

With or without the `aes(colour = series)` in the `geom_line` results in the same graph.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's hard to help without a [mcve].  Can you provide example data?  Check the datatypes of your melted columns. Are they what you expect?  Also, you shouldn't need to re-specify `color = series` after you set it in the call to `ggplot`.

Comment: I assume your plan is to connect the dots of each series. For a `geom_line()` layer to know which points (x, y positions) to connect, you need to specify the `group` parameter. Thus ... + geom_line(aes(..., group = series)) should do the trick.

Comment: Andrew, thanks.  I did find that color = series didn't need to be added twice -- just gasping straws.  Don't really understand this yet.

Comment: Ray, this fixed it!  I didn't see a group parameter in all the examples I looked at but saw the group parameter in the documentation when you pointed it out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Understanding the "inheritence of aesthetics" in `{ggplot}` can be a challenge in the beginning. The following might explain what `geom_line()` does when you specify aesthetics in the `ggplot()` call.

Note: I assign a deliberate colour column that differs from the series specification!

```
df <- data.frame(
   x = c(1,2,3,4,5)
 , y = c(2,2,3,4,2)
 , colour = factor(c(rep(1,3), rep(2,2)))
 , series = c(1,1,2,3,3)
)

df
  x y colour series
1 1 2      1      1
2 2 2      1      1
3 3 3      1      2
4 4 4      2      3
5 5 2      2      3
```

Inheritance in ggplot will look for aesthetics defined in an upper layer.
Thus, with no (further) aesthetics defined in the `geom_point()` layer, this layer will look for the specification in the upper layer, i.e. `ggplot()`.

Please note further that the `colour` aesthetic in the `ggplot()` layer is interpreted as a grouping (in the absence of a specific `group` aesthetic).

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = colour)) + 
   geom_point(size = 3) +    # setting the size to stress point layer call
   geom_line()               # geom_line will "inherit" a "grouping" from the colour set above
```

This gives you
[image: group inherited from colour]

While we can control the "grouping" associated to each line(segment) as follows:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = colour)) + 
   geom_point(size = 3) + 
   geom_line(aes(group = series)    # defining specific grouping
)
```

Note: As I defined a separate "group" in the series column for the 3rd point, it is depicted - in this case - as a single point "line".

[image: geom_line() with defined group parameter]